# how to get maximum value from casts object field in laravel eloquent model

Tags: laravel-5.4, eloquent

My model

```
class Applicant extends Model {

    protected $dates = [ 'date_of_birth', 'sent_by_post_date' ];

    protected $table = 'applicants';

    protected $casts = [ 'application_no' => 'object' ];
}
```

records stored in `application_no`, Key could be increase ... [A, B,C,D,.....]

```
1. {
    "A" : 1,
    "C" : 1,
    }
2. {
    "A" : 2,
    "B" : 1,
    }
3. {
    "A" : 3,
    "B" : 2,
    }
4. {
    "A" : 4,
    "B" : 3,
    }
5. {
    "A" : 5,
    "C" : 2,
    "D" : 1,
    }
```

Now i want to get the maximum application_no of `A` or `B` ..... wise...

```
public function getMaximumApplicationNo($shortCode){
    return Applicant::max("application_no.$shortCode" );
}
```